# Starting a firefox extension when firefox starts up

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I wrote a firefox extension to process response and requests. Right now its activated by clicking a menu button. I would like the extension to start running when firefox boots up. Is this possible? Ideally the only interface I want/need to have is inside the add-on manager (disable/uninstall)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, register an overlay on `browser.xul` in your manifest file:

```
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://sample/content/sample.xul
```

Then, include some JavaScript in your `sample.xul`. This JavaScript should attach an `onload` event handler to the window. This will fire every time a new browser window is opened and your code will run.

Alternatively, if you need just one instance of your code to be shared among all windows, consider a full-blown [XPCOM component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_XPCOM_Components), in which you can register to [listen for the `profile-after-change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications) event, which is one of the earliest events that occurs on startup, after the profile directory and other services have been established.